# Is there any API to automatically spin up AWS server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible

I might be naive but looking for a good solution to automatically spin up an AWS server with an API.

The use case is to create AWS EC2 instances on a click and maintain the deployments. Ansible is a probable candidate but looking for the core solution of spinning up a new EC2 machine.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: There are lots of ways to do this and reading the AWS docs would tell you how to do this, even if you are inexperienced

Comment: Just in amazon world: cloudformation or opswork - you could also use [Terraform](https://www.terraform.io/) ; note Ansible is nice to provision an instance (meaning install packages) but not to so good to setup your instance

Comment: Even [a cursory search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=ansible+aws&ia=about) would find [the Ansible marketing page about AWS](https://www.ansible.com/aws) and [the technical guide](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/guide_aws.html).

Comment: As I stated, I am looking for something more than Ansible.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than directly calling an API (eg from Java, .Net, Python, etc), you can also use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/).

The command you want is `run-instances`, which will launch a new Amazon EC2 instance.

See: [AWS CLI documentation for `run-instances`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/run-instances.html)